# For a specific $v$ in $V$, let $p(x)$ be the monic polynomial such that $p(T)v=0$. Then $p$ divides the minimal polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

[image]

Before starting problem, I was wondering why we assume that the degree of $p$ is smaller or equal to the degree of the minimal polynomial. Intuitively, it makes a lot of sense since the minimal polynomial applied to all vectors in $V$ is $0$ where as $p(T)$ was specifically constructed just so $p(T)v=0$, so $p$ does not need to carry as much information as the minimal polynomial, but how do we rigorously show this?

Comment: You can show directly that it divides the minimal polynomial and therefore it has lower degree

Comment: Or you can just look at the definition of $p$, because if $q$ is the minimal polynomial of $T$, you have $q(T)=0$ so $q(T)v=0$ and $p$ is the smallest polynomial satisfying this

Comment: @AitorIribarLopez ok that logically makes a lot more sense and logical sounding

Answer (score 1):

Let $f$ be the minimal polynomial of $T$. Then $f$ is monic and $f(T)v = 0$, so, as $p$ is the monic polynomial with minimal degree such that $p(T)v = 0$, $\deg(p) \le \deg(f)$. Note the fact $(*)$ that any non-zero polynomial $g$ such that $g(T)v = 0$ has $\deg(g) \ge \deg(p)$ (because we can turn $g$ into a monic polynomial with the same property by dividing it by its leading coefficient). Using polynomial division, we know that there are polynomials $q$ and $r$, such that $f = qp + r$ and either $r = 0$ or $\deg(r) < \deg(p)$. But $r(T)v = f(T)v - (q(T)p(T))v = 0$, so if $r \neq 0$, this contradicts fact $(*)$.

Answer (score 0):

With some ring theory: Let $k$ be the field of coefficients. Then $k[T]$ is a principal ideal domain. The set of polynomials $f$ defined by $f(T)v=0$ is an ideal and generated by $p$. The minimal polynomial is element of the ideal and therefore divisible by $p$.